# Naming Inconsistency

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

My app was rejected because of the naming inconsistency. The name entered into iTunes Connect must match the name of the application installed

However, the after iphone sdk3.0, the product name cannot contain illegal characters such as space.

So how can I name my application with spaces in it like "MyApp Lite"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaped characters like "MyApp%20Lite"?

Comment: it shouldn't work, because space is considered illegal character for bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they mean the product name (yourApp.app). In my experience, the name can be quite different. For example you app could be named "A very useful app" in iTunes and have a product name like "useful.app". I am sure of that.

So the inconsistency lies elsewhere. I assume that the reason that your app was rejected was because the name you entered in iTunes Connect does not correspond to the app. That's just an assumption of course. Are you telling us the whole story? The Apple review team is usually quite descriptive of the reason they reject.

That being said, this question is not programming related.